# How to create ggraph reactive layout in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, igraph, reactive, ggraph

so I've been working on this app looking at BC's drug checking data (see [here](https://alexbetsos.shinyapps.io/DC_BC/)), and I wanted to make my ggraph plots a bit more interactive, so that people could more readily see the connections between different nodes, by clicking over hovering over them. Whenever I try to put the create_layout() into a reactive function, however, I get

> Warning: Error in E: Not a graph object

I need the layout to be in a reactive function, so it can be read by renderPrint, for something I'm trying to add. When I've run print(class(layout())) as a reactive it shows the same properties as when run within renderPlot.

The whole code is a bit complicated, but the working version is available here: https://github.com/alexbetsos/DC_Shiny, I've provided a simpler version with the error below. Unfortunately, some aspects can't be simplified, but I've tried my best.

All of the slider-related content can be ignored - it's probably not good form but it works fairly well.

To note I have the nodes and edges as reactives because they're used in other places as in the larger shiny project. The only major issue here atm is that I can't figure out how to have the layout function as a reactive.

All help appreciated.

In order to make the data reproducible, and so everything else functions I've uploaded a small sample of the data to github, so that the slider still functions correctly, however, I've limited it to just 1 expected substance.

````
library(readr)
urlfile <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexbetsos/stackoverflowhelp/main/test_data.csv"
test_data <- read_csv(url(urlfile))
test_data <- test_data[,-c(1)]

poss.w <- data.frame(ID = c(80,81,82,83),
 Days2 = c("Jun 28-\nJul 4\n2021",
 "Jul 5-\nJul 11\n2021",
"Jul 12-\nJul 18\n2021",
"Jul 19-\nJul 25\n2021"))
get_id <- c(max(poss.w$ID)-1, max(poss.w$ID))

interest <- c("Fentanyl/Down", "Opioids Minus Fentanyl (Grouped)", "All Opioids (Grouped)", "Methamphetamine",
              "Ketamine", "Cocaine", "Crack Cocaine", "MDMA")

test_data <- test_data[test_data$Expected.Substance %in% interest,] 


###Creates df for classification and the colour palette####
node_col <- structure(list(ID = 1:36, 
                           Names = c("Caffeine", "Erythritol", 
                                    "Uncertain Match", "Fent <5%", "Fentanyl or Analog", "Xylitol", 
                                    "Benzodiazepine <5%", "Mannitol", "Uncertain Oil/Carb/Sugar", 
                                    "Dimethyl Sulfone", "Soap", "Water", "Methamphetamine", "Acetaminophen", 
                                    "para-Fluorofentanyl", "No Cuts\nFentanyl or Analog", "No Cuts\nUncertain Match", 
                                    "Propionanilide", "MDMA", "Safrole", "Sucrose", "Phenacetin", 
                                    "4-ANPP", "Lactose", "Inositol", "Creatine", "Etizolam",
                                    "No Cuts\nTrichloroisocyanuric Acid", 
                                    "Naproxen", "Heroin", "PEG", "Diphenhydramine", "Cocaine", "Glutamine", 
                                    "Benzocaine", "Sorbitol"), 
                           Classification = c("Stimulant", "Buff", 
                                              "Other or NA", "Opioid", "Opioid", "Buff", "Benzodiazepine", 
                                              "Buff", "Other or NA", "Buff", "new_val", "Other or NA", "Stimulant", 
                                              "Buff", "Opioid", "Opioid", "Other or NA", "Buff", "Stimulant", 
                                              "Other or NA", "Buff", "Buff", "Precursor", "Buff", "Buff", "Other or NA", 
                                              "Benzodiazepine", "new_val", "new_val", "Opioid", "Buff", "Other or NA", 
                                              "Stimulant", "Buff", "Buff", "Buff")), row.names = c(NA, -36L
                                              ), class = "data.frame")

regrouped <- data.frame(ID = seq(2000, 1999+length(unique(node_col$Classification)),by=1),
                        Names = unique(unique(node_col$Classification)),
                        Classification = unique(unique(node_col$Classification)))
node_col <- rbind(node_col, regrouped)



####---Libraries & Functions---####
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
library(tidygraph)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)
ui <- navbarPage(title = "BC Drug Checking Visualizations",theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                 tabPanel("Instructions",
                          tabPanel("Drug Checking Data",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                                                  selectInput("Drug",
                                                              "Expected Substance",
                                                              choices = interest,
                                                              selected = NULL),
                                                  selectInput("City",
                                                              "City",
                                                              choices = unique(test_data$City.Town),
                                                              selected = "Vancouver"),
                                                  radioButtons("duration",
                                                               label = "1 Week or Multiple",
                                                               choices = c("1 Week", "Multiple"),
                                                               selected = "1 Week"),
                                                  checkboxGroupInput("regroup",
                                                                     label = "Regroup Variables",
                                                                     choices = regrouped$Classification,
                                                                     selected = NULL)
                                                  
                                     ),
                                     mainPanel(width = 9,
                                               fluidRow(
                                                 uiOutput("myList")),
                                               tabsetPanel(
                                                 tabPanel("Network Graph",
                                                          fluidRow(tabstyle='padding:0px',
                                                                   box(width = 12, 
                                                                       offset = 0,
                                                                       plotOutput("net", width = "100%",
                                                                                  height = "750px",
                                                                                  click = "plot_click",
                                                                                  brush = "plot_brush"))),
                                                          fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("info"))
                                                          
                                                          #Need to add the bar chart & Table back in
                                                 )
                                               )
                          )))))
                                   
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Create reactive value to hold slider info
  slidertype <- reactiveValues()
  
  slidertype$type <- "default"
  observeEvent(input$duration, {
    #When person changes from 1 week to multiple it will change slider
    if(input$duration == "1 Week"){
      slidertype$type <- "1 Week"
    } else if(input$duration == "Multiple"){
      slidertype$type <- "Multiple"
    } else {
      slidertype$type <- "default"
    }
  })
  #Renders the UI for the slider
  output$myList <- renderUI({
    #Changes based on whether someone selects output
    if(slidertype$type == "1 Week"){
      sliderTextInput("Change",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = as.character(poss.w$Days2),
                      selected = as.character(poss.w$Days2[poss.w$ID == max(get_id)]),
                      force_edges = TRUE,
                      width = "1200px")
    } else if(slidertype$type == "Multiple") {
      sliderTextInput("Change",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = as.character(poss.w$Days2),
                      selected = as.character(poss.w$Days2[poss.w$ID %in% get_id]),
                      force_edges = TRUE,
                      width = "1200px")
    } else{
      sliderTextInput("Change",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = as.character(poss.w$Days2),
                      selected = as.character(poss.w$Days2[poss.w$ID == max(get_id)]),
                      force_edges = TRUE, width = "1200px")
    }
  })
  #Create reactive df - requires different filtering
  df_react <- reactive({
    if(slidertype$type != "Multiple"){
      test_data%>%
        filter(Expected.Substance == input$Drug & Week.val %in% input$Change & City.Town == input$City)
    } else if (slidertype$type == "Multiple") {
      test_data %>%
        filter(Expected.Substance == input$Drug & Week.val <= input$Change[2] &
                 Week.val >=input$Change[1] & City.Town == input$City)
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$City,{
    poss_e <- poss.w[poss.w$Days2 <= max(test_data$Week.val[test_data$City.Town == input$City]) & poss.w$Days2 >= min(test_data$Week.val[test_data$City.Town == input$City]),]
    if(slidertype$type != "Multiple"){
      new_id <- max(poss_e$ID)
      updateSliderTextInput(session,inputId = "Change", choices = as.character(poss_e$Days2), selected = as.character(poss_e$Days2[poss_e$ID == max(get_id)]))
    } else {
      new_id <- c(max(poss_e$ID)-1, max(poss_e$ID))
      updateSliderTextInput(session,inputId = "Change", choices = as.character(poss_e$Days2), selected = as.character(poss_e$Days2[poss_e$ID %in% get_id]))
    }
  })
  
  df_react2 <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$regroup)){
      df_react() %>%
        dplyr::rename(Names = value) %>%
        left_join(node_col[,c(2:3)]) %>%
        mutate(Classification2 = ifelse(Classification %in% input$regroup, Classification, Names)) %>%
        rename(value = Classification2)
    } else {
      df_react()
    }
  })
  
  #Nodes for the Social Network Visualization
  nodes <- reactive({
    node <-  df_react2() %>%
      select(value) %>%
      count(value) %>%
      dplyr::rename(Names = value, Weight = n) %>%
      left_join(node_col) %>%
      select(ID, Names, Weight, Classification) %>%
      arrange(desc(Weight))
    node$Weight[grepl("No Cuts", node$Names)] <- node$Weight[grepl("No Cuts", node$Names)]/2
    return(node)
  })
  #Edges for SN
  #The nesting solution was a huge help from a user on stackoverflow
  #This code doesn't work without it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63083986/7263991
  edges2 <- reactive({
    if(nrow(df_react2()) != 0){
      df_react2() %>%
        select(ID, value) %>%
        nest(data=(value)) %>%
        mutate(pairs=map(data, ~as_tibble(t(combn(.$value, 2))), .name_repair=T, .keep)) %>%
        unnest(pairs) %>%
        select(V1, V2) %>%
        group_by(V1, V2) %>%
        summarise(amount = n()) %>%
        ungroup()
    } else {
      df_react2()
    }
  })
the_layout <- reactive({
  edges <- edges2()
  validate(
    need(nrow(edges) >0.9, "Not tested During this Time")
  )
  colnames(edges) <- c("to", "from", "weight")
  edges$from <- nodes()$ID[match(edges$from, nodes()$Names)]
  edges$to <- nodes()$ID[match(edges$to, nodes()$Names)]
  edges <- select(edges, from, to, weight)
  
  g <- graph_from_data_frame(d = edges, vertices = nodes(), directed = FALSE) 
  g <- simplify(g, remove.loops = TRUE)
  if(input$Drug %in% c(V(g)$Names, "Fentanyl/Down", "All Opioids (Grouped)") & 
     nrow(edges) >=10){
    #Checks if there is just one graph or several
    if(is.connected(g) == FALSE){
      #if true then, it splits the main graph from the subgraphs
      c <- clusters(g); cn <- cbind(V(g), c$membership)
      lc <- which(which.max(c$csize)==c$membership);
      gs <- induced.subgraph(g, lc)
      if(input$Drug == "All Opioids (Grouped)"|input$Drug == "Fentanyl/Down"){
        st1 <- layout_as_star(gs, center = V(gs)$Names == "Fentanyl or Analog")
        
      }else{
        st1 <- layout_as_star(gs, center = V(gs)$Names == input$Drug)
      }
      st1 <- norm_coords(st1, xmin = -0.6, xmax = 0.6, 
                         ymin = -0.6, ymax = +0.6,
                         zmin = -0.6, zmax = +0.6)
      #Normalize even and odd rows at different min & max to stagger nodes
      st1[seq(2, nrow(st1),2),] <- norm_coords(st1[seq(2, nrow(st1),2),],
                                               xmin = -0.45, xmax = 0.45, 
                                               ymin = -0.45, ymax = +0.45,
                                               zmin = -0.45, zmax = +0.45)
      lc2 <- which(!which.max(c$csize)==c$membership)
      gs2 <- induced.subgraph(g, lc2)
      circ <- layout_in_circle(gs2)
      circ <- norm_coords(circ, xmin = -0.8, xmax = 0.8, 
                          ymin = -0.8, ymax = +0.8,
                          zmin = -0.8, zmax = +0.8)
      test2 <- rbind(st1,circ) 
      g <- gs %du% gs2
      t_lay <- create_layout(g, test2)
      
    }else{
      st1 <- layout_as_star(g, center = V(g)$Names == input$Drug)
      st1 <- norm_coords(st1, xmin = -0.8, xmax = 0.8, 
                         ymin = -0.8, ymax = +0.8,
                         zmin = -0.8, zmax = +0.8)
      t_lay <- create_layout(g, st1)
    }
    #For every other drug sample - still WIP
  } else {
    t_lay <- create_layout(g, layout = "nicely")
    
  }
})
  #Set graph space limits
output$net <- renderPlot({ 
  t_lay <- the_layout()
  x_max <- max(t_lay$x)+0.1
  x_min <- min(t_lay$x)-0.1
  y_min <- min(t_lay$y)-0.1
  y_max <- max(t_lay$y)+0.1
  par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
  ggraph(t_lay) +
    geom_edge_link0(aes(width = E(g)$weight), colour = "grey") +   # add edges to the plot
    scale_edge_width_continuous(breaks = c(1, 5, 10, 25, 50,100),
                                label = c(1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100),
                                range = c(1,20), name = "Frequency Found Together",
                                limits = c(0,400),
                                guide = guide_legend(order = 2, 
                                                     nrow = 1,
                                                     ncol =7)) +
    geom_node_point(aes(size = V(g)$Weight, color = V(g)$Classification)) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(y_min, y_max), xlim = c(x_min, x_max)) +
    geom_node_text(aes(label = V(g)$Names), angle = 30, size = 5) +
    scale_size(breaks = c(1,10,20,40, 60,80, 100), label=scales::number,
               range = c(1,60), limits = c(1,400), name = "# of Times Drug Found \n in Test Results",
               guide = guide_legend(order = 1,
                                    nrow = 4,
                                    ncol = 2,
                                    label.hjust =0.5)) +
    labs(caption = "Fent/Benzodiazepine < 5% means substance tested positive on test strip") +
    theme(legend.position= "right",
          legend.box.background = element_blank(),
          legend.direction = "vertical",
          legend.key = element_blank(),
          legend.background = element_blank(),
          legend.text = element_text(size=12, hjust  = 0.4, inherit.blank = TRUE),
          legend.box.just = "top",
          legend.box = "vertical",
          legend.justification = "right",
          legend.box.spacing = unit(0.5,"cm"),
          plot.caption = element_text(size = 14),
          legend.title.align = 0.2,
          legend.text.align = 0.4,
          legend.title=element_text(size=14),
          legend.key.width = unit(0.5, "cm"),
          legend.key.height = unit(0.2, "cm"),
          legend.spacing = unit(0.5, "cm"),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          legend.box.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0, unit = "cm"),
          legend.margin = margin(0,0, 0, 0, unit = "cm"))+
    guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=10),
                                nrow = 5,
                                ncol = 4))
  
})
#I would like to do something like this
output$info <- renderPrint({
  brushedPoints(the_layout(), input$plot_brush, allRows = TRUE)})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the shiny app to work by changing the assignment of `g` from `<-` to `<<-`. The amended code is below for you.

```
urlfile <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexbetsos/stackoverflowhelp/main/test_data.csv"
test_data <- read_csv(url(urlfile))
test_data <- test_data[,-c(1)]

poss.w <- data.frame(ID = c(80,81,82,83),
                     Days2 = c("Jun 28-\nJul 4\n2021",
                               "Jul 5-\nJul 11\n2021",
                               "Jul 12-\nJul 18\n2021",
                               "Jul 19-\nJul 25\n2021"))
get_id <- c(max(poss.w$ID)-1, max(poss.w$ID))

interest <- c("Fentanyl/Down", "Opioids Minus Fentanyl (Grouped)", "All Opioids (Grouped)", "Methamphetamine",
              "Ketamine", "Cocaine", "Crack Cocaine", "MDMA")

test_data <- test_data[test_data$Expected.Substance %in% interest,] 


###Creates df for classification and the colour palette####
node_col <- structure(list(ID = 1:36, 
                           Names = c("Caffeine", "Erythritol", 
                                     "Uncertain Match", "Fent <5%", "Fentanyl or Analog", "Xylitol", 
                                     "Benzodiazepine <5%", "Mannitol", "Uncertain Oil/Carb/Sugar", 
                                     "Dimethyl Sulfone", "Soap", "Water", "Methamphetamine", "Acetaminophen", 
                                     "para-Fluorofentanyl", "No Cuts\nFentanyl or Analog", "No Cuts\nUncertain Match", 
                                     "Propionanilide", "MDMA", "Safrole", "Sucrose", "Phenacetin", 
                                     "4-ANPP", "Lactose", "Inositol", "Creatine", "Etizolam",
                                     "No Cuts\nTrichloroisocyanuric Acid", 
                                     "Naproxen", "Heroin", "PEG", "Diphenhydramine", "Cocaine", "Glutamine", 
                                     "Benzocaine", "Sorbitol"), 
                           Classification = c("Stimulant", "Buff", 
                                              "Other or NA", "Opioid", "Opioid", "Buff", "Benzodiazepine", 
                                              "Buff", "Other or NA", "Buff", "new_val", "Other or NA", "Stimulant", 
                                              "Buff", "Opioid", "Opioid", "Other or NA", "Buff", "Stimulant", 
                                              "Other or NA", "Buff", "Buff", "Precursor", "Buff", "Buff", "Other or NA", 
                                              "Benzodiazepine", "new_val", "new_val", "Opioid", "Buff", "Other or NA", 
                                              "Stimulant", "Buff", "Buff", "Buff")), row.names = c(NA, -36L
                                              ), class = "data.frame")

regrouped <- data.frame(ID = seq(2000, 1999+length(unique(node_col$Classification)),by=1),
                        Names = unique(unique(node_col$Classification)),
                        Classification = unique(unique(node_col$Classification)))
node_col <- rbind(node_col, regrouped)



####---Libraries & Functions---####
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
library(tidygraph)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)
ui <- navbarPage(title = "BC Drug Checking Visualizations",theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                 tabPanel("Instructions",
                          tabPanel("Drug Checking Data",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                                                  selectInput("Drug",
                                                              "Expected Substance",
                                                              choices = interest,
                                                              selected = NULL),
                                                  selectInput("City",
                                                              "City",
                                                              choices = unique(test_data$City.Town),
                                                              selected = "Vancouver"),
                                                  radioButtons("duration",
                                                               label = "1 Week or Multiple",
                                                               choices = c("1 Week", "Multiple"),
                                                               selected = "1 Week"),
                                                  checkboxGroupInput("regroup",
                                                                     label = "Regroup Variables",
                                                                     choices = regrouped$Classification,
                                                                     selected = NULL)
                                                  
                                     ),
                                     mainPanel(width = 9,
                                               fluidRow(
                                                 uiOutput("myList")),
                                               tabsetPanel(
                                                 tabPanel("Network Graph",
                                                          fluidRow(tabstyle='padding:0px',
                                                                   box(width = 12, 
                                                                       offset = 0,
                                                                       plotlOutput("net", width = "100%",
                                                                                  height = "750px",
                                                                                  click = "plot_click",
                                                                                  brush = "plot_brush"))),
                                                          fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("info"))
                                                          
                                                          #Need to add the bar chart & Table back in
                                                 )
                                               )
                                     )))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Create reactive value to hold slider info
  slidertype <- reactiveValues()
  
  slidertype$type <- "default"
  observeEvent(input$duration, {
    #When person changes from 1 week to multiple it will change slider
    if(input$duration == "1 Week"){
      slidertype$type <- "1 Week"
    } else if(input$duration == "Multiple"){
      slidertype$type <- "Multiple"
    } else {
      slidertype$type <- "default"
    }
  })
  #Renders the UI for the slider
  output$myList <- renderUI({
    #Changes based on whether someone selects output
    if(slidertype$type == "1 Week"){
      sliderTextInput("Change",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = as.character(poss.w$Days2),
                      selected = as.character(poss.w$Days2[poss.w$ID == max(get_id)]),
                      force_edges = TRUE,
                      width = "1200px")
    } else if(slidertype$type == "Multiple") {
      sliderTextInput("Change",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = as.character(poss.w$Days2),
                      selected = as.character(poss.w$Days2[poss.w$ID %in% get_id]),
                      force_edges = TRUE,
                      width = "1200px")
    } else{
      sliderTextInput("Change",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = as.character(poss.w$Days2),
                      selected = as.character(poss.w$Days2[poss.w$ID == max(get_id)]),
                      force_edges = TRUE, width = "1200px")
    }
  })
  #Create reactive df - requires different filtering
  df_react <- reactive({
    if(slidertype$type != "Multiple"){
      test_data %>%
        filter(Expected.Substance == input$Drug & Week.val %in% input$Change & City.Town == input$City)
    } else if (slidertype$type == "Multiple") {
      test_data %>%
        filter(Expected.Substance == input$Drug & Week.val <= input$Change[2] &
                 Week.val >=input$Change[1] & City.Town == input$City)
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$City,{
    poss_e <- poss.w[poss.w$Days2 <= max(test_data$Week.val[test_data$City.Town == input$City]) & poss.w$Days2 >= min(test_data$Week.val[test_data$City.Town == input$City]),]
    if(slidertype$type != "Multiple"){
      new_id <- max(poss_e$ID)
      updateSliderTextInput(session,inputId = "Change", choices = as.character(poss_e$Days2), selected = as.character(poss_e$Days2[poss_e$ID == max(get_id)]))
    } else {
      new_id <- c(max(poss_e$ID)-1, max(poss_e$ID))
      updateSliderTextInput(session,inputId = "Change", choices = as.character(poss_e$Days2), selected = as.character(poss_e$Days2[poss_e$ID %in% get_id]))
    }
  })
  
  df_react2 <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$regroup)){
      df_react() %>%
        dplyr::rename(Names = value) %>%
        left_join(node_col[,c(2:3)]) %>%
        mutate(Classification2 = ifelse(Classification %in% input$regroup, Classification, Names)) %>%
        rename(value = Classification2)
    } else {
      df_react()
    }
  })
  
  #Nodes for the Social Network Visualization
  nodes <- reactive({
    node <-  df_react2() %>%
      select(value) %>%
      count(value) %>%
      dplyr::rename(Names = value, Weight = n) %>%
      left_join(node_col) %>%
      select(ID, Names, Weight, Classification) %>%
      arrange(desc(Weight))
    node$Weight[grepl("No Cuts", node$Names)] <- node$Weight[grepl("No Cuts", node$Names)]/2
    return(node)
  })
  #Edges for SN
  #The nesting solution was a huge help from a user on stackoverflow
  #This code doesn't work without it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63083986/7263991
  edges2 <- reactive({
    if(nrow(df_react2()) != 0){
      df_react2() %>%
        select(ID, value) %>%
        nest(data=(value)) %>%
        mutate(pairs=map(data, ~as_tibble(t(combn(.$value, 2))), .name_repair=T, .keep)) %>%
        unnest(pairs) %>%
        select(V1, V2) %>%
        group_by(V1, V2) %>%
        summarise(amount = n()) %>%
        ungroup()
    } else {
      df_react2()
    }
  })
  the_layout <- reactive({
    edges <- edges2()
    validate(
      need(nrow(edges) >0.9, "Not tested During this Time")
    )
    colnames(edges) <- c("to", "from", "weight")
    edges$from <- nodes()$ID[match(edges$from, nodes()$Names)]
    edges$to <- nodes()$ID[match(edges$to, nodes()$Names)]
    edges <- select(edges, from, to, weight)
    
    g <<- graph_from_data_frame(d = edges, vertices = nodes(), directed = FALSE) 
    g <<- simplify(g, remove.loops = TRUE)
    if(input$Drug %in% c(V(g)$Names, "Fentanyl/Down", "All Opioids (Grouped)") & 
       nrow(edges) >=10){
      #Checks if there is just one graph or several
      if(is.connected(g) == FALSE){
        #if true then, it splits the main graph from the subgraphs
        c <- clusters(g); cn <- cbind(V(g), c$membership)
        lc <- which(which.max(c$csize)==c$membership);
        gs <- induced.subgraph(g, lc)
        if(input$Drug == "All Opioids (Grouped)"|input$Drug == "Fentanyl/Down"){
          st1 <- layout_as_star(gs, center = V(gs)$Names == "Fentanyl or Analog")
          
        }else{
          st1 <- layout_as_star(gs, center = V(gs)$Names == input$Drug)
        }
        st1 <- norm_coords(st1, xmin = -0.6, xmax = 0.6, 
                           ymin = -0.6, ymax = +0.6,
                           zmin = -0.6, zmax = +0.6)
        #Normalize even and odd rows at different min & max to stagger nodes
        st1[seq(2, nrow(st1),2),] <- norm_coords(st1[seq(2, nrow(st1),2),],
                                                 xmin = -0.45, xmax = 0.45, 
                                                 ymin = -0.45, ymax = +0.45,
                                                 zmin = -0.45, zmax = +0.45)
        lc2 <- which(!which.max(c$csize)==c$membership)
        gs2 <- induced.subgraph(g, lc2)
        circ <- layout_in_circle(gs2)
        circ <- norm_coords(circ, xmin = -0.8, xmax = 0.8, 
                            ymin = -0.8, ymax = +0.8,
                            zmin = -0.8, zmax = +0.8)
        test2 <- rbind(st1,circ) 
        g <- gs %du% gs2
        t_lay <- create_layout(g, test2)
        
      }else{
        st1 <- layout_as_star(g, center = V(g)$Names == input$Drug)
        st1 <- norm_coords(st1, xmin = -0.8, xmax = 0.8, 
                           ymin = -0.8, ymax = +0.8,
                           zmin = -0.8, zmax = +0.8)
        t_lay <- create_layout(g, st1)
      }
      #For every other drug sample - still WIP
    } else {
      t_lay <- create_layout(g, layout = "nicely")
      
    }
  })
  #Set graph space limits
  output$net <- renderPlot({ 
    t_lay <<- the_layout()
    x_max <- max(t_lay$x)+0.1
    x_min <- min(t_lay$x)-0.1
    y_min <- min(t_lay$y)-0.1
    y_max <- max(t_lay$y)+0.1
    par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
    ggraph(t_lay) +
      geom_edge_link0(aes(width = E(g)$weight), colour = "grey") +   # add edges to the plot
      scale_edge_width_continuous(breaks = c(1, 5, 10, 25, 50,100),
                                  label = c(1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100),
                                  range = c(1,20), name = "Frequency Found Together",
                                  limits = c(0,400),
                                  guide = guide_legend(order = 2, 
                                                       nrow = 1,
                                                       ncol =7)) +
      geom_node_point(aes(size = V(g)$Weight, color = V(g)$Classification)) +
      coord_cartesian(ylim = c(y_min, y_max), xlim = c(x_min, x_max)) +
      geom_node_text(aes(label = V(g)$Names), angle = 30, size = 5) +
      scale_size(breaks = c(1,10,20,40, 60,80, 100), label=scales::number,
                 range = c(1,60), limits = c(1,400), name = "# of Times Drug Found \n in Test Results",
                 guide = guide_legend(order = 1,
                                      nrow = 4,
                                      ncol = 2,
                                      label.hjust =0.5)) +
      labs(caption = "Fent/Benzodiazepine < 5% means substance tested positive on test strip") +
      theme(legend.position= "right",
            legend.box.background = element_blank(),
            legend.direction = "vertical",
            legend.key = element_blank(),
            legend.background = element_blank(),
            legend.text = element_text(size=12, hjust  = 0.4, inherit.blank = TRUE),
            legend.box.just = "top",
            legend.box = "vertical",
            legend.justification = "right",
            legend.box.spacing = unit(0.5,"cm"),
            plot.caption = element_text(size = 14),
            legend.title.align = 0.2,
            legend.text.align = 0.4,
            legend.title=element_text(size=14),
            legend.key.width = unit(0.5, "cm"),
            legend.key.height = unit(0.2, "cm"),
            legend.spacing = unit(0.5, "cm"),
            panel.background = element_blank(),
            legend.box.margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0, unit = "cm"),
            legend.margin = margin(0,0, 0, 0, unit = "cm"))+
      guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=10),
                                  nrow = 5,
                                  ncol = 4))
    
  })
  #I would like to do something like this
  output$info <- renderPrint({
    brushedPoints(the_layout(), input$plot_brush, allRows = TRUE)})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Did not know scoping assignments were a thing thank you so much Lauren <3